# How to setup a right GIT flow for a huge company with many releases

Tags: git, github, version-control

We need to improve our Git flow setup as we face several problems currently in our company.

Our current lifecycle:

- We code a white-labeled product for multiple companies from one repo
- 20+ devs code ~30 pull requests (we use Github) every day
- We push all our code to `master` branch
- Each 2nd week we create `release/2018-xx` from `master`
- This release is tested and used by five companies
- All of them report us bugs the following weeks
- We merge those bugs into `master` and cherrypick them into `release/xx`
- Whenever each company decides, they put `release/xx` into production
- When they deploy we destroy

Problems we face:

1) Even we have a "stable" release in which we put **only** bugfixes, we still do this for all five companies and sometimes a bugfix of one of them destroys functionality of another (=> creating four release branches and cherrypicking all fixed into all five would be extremely time consuming)

2) We have to cherry pick more than 20 fixes from `master` into `release/2018-xx` every single day and fix a lot of conflicts (alternative is to branch a bugfix from the release branch, but we would face conflicts then into master)

Is there any approach how to handle such a heavy flow?

Comment: "We push all our code to master branch" seems like that is the part to change. Work fixes in topic branches branched from the target release, then sort out the merge into master: merge in from master to resolve conflicts before merging into master. (Depending on cherry pick is going to be problematic). TL;DR: you appear to be using a "traditional-VCS" workflow rather than a git orientated workflow.

Comment: "When they deploy we destroy"—why?

Comment: Respectfully, this isn't "heavy" Git usage. As Richard suggests, learn to use branches more effectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## High Level Considerations

There are a couple dimensions to this problem that need to be considered:

- The customer's expectations.
- The stability of the product's feature set.

Given these two things you need to establish:

- A release cycle.
- A versioning scheme.
- A branching strategy.

The main tradeoffs that you're dealing with when choosing a release cycle are and versioning scheme are:

- Delivering new features to customers quickly at the rate they expect. VS. Releasing features slowly enough so that your head doesn't explode.
- Providing a stable feature set. VS. Breaking backward compatibility to make significant technical improvements to the product.
- Supporting a particular version for a Customer for a significant duration of time. VS. Minimizing the number of versions that you have to support.

Let's dive into a versioning scheme first because that is the simplest. After that is defined, we can discuss a complimentary branching strategy, and finally a release cycle that suites your needs.

## Versioning Scheme

There is a well defined way of versioning software called [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/). The main idea behind semantic versioning is that a software version is composed of three parts:

- Major Version
- Minor Version
- Patch Version

These three versions are numbers and combined with dots. `{Major Version}.{Minor Version}.{Path Version}`.

Examples of valid semantic versions are: 1.0.0, 2.1.0, 11.1.133

### Major Version

A major version change indicates a backward incompatible change has taken place. Specifically let's say your product is currently version 1.0.0 . And you decide to make a bunch of changes that remove features or change the way existing features work, and you want to release this new version. Since you've made changes that could break existing users of the software you need to increase the major version, so that the new version of the product is 2.0.0 . Similarly if your changes don't break old features then you can keep the same major version when you release the next version of the software.

### Minor Version

A minor version change indicates that new features have been added, and that everything is still backward compatible with the previous version. So let's say you have a 1.0.0 product, and you add a new button that does something cool, but everything else works exactly the same. Then the next version of the product should 1.1.0 .

### Patch Version

A patch version change indicates that one or more bugs have been fixed. No new features were added and no existing features were changed.

### How User's Interpret Versions

These are the possible motivations for users picking a version:

- **A user wants the latest greatest version to start something new:** Then the user would pick the released version that has the highest major version, minor version, and patch version.
- **A user wants some new features, but they don't want anything they are currently using in the product to change**: Then the user picks the release that has the same major version as the version they are using now, but they look for the highest minor and patch version.
- **A user wants bug fixes and doesn't want to risk doing a major upgrade**: In this case users look for releases with the same major and minor versions as what they are currently using, but they pick the release with the highest patch version.

## Branching Strategy

There is a pretty common branching strategy that complements semantic versioning. The general idea is that for each unique major and minor version pair you create a release branch. For example if you have the following versions:

- 1.0.0
- 1.0.1
- 1.1.0
- 1.1.1
- 1.1.2
- 1.1.3
- 1.2.0

You will maintain the following git branches:

- release-1.0
- release-1.1
- release-1.2

Each of these release branches essentially has the code corresponding to the latest patch version:

- release-1.0: has the code for 1.0.1
- release-1.1: has the code for 1.1.2
- release-1.2: has the code for 1.2.0

You also have a **master** branch which has the latest code under development.

**Note:** There is no destruction of branches. These branches stick around as you keep on adding bug fixes to them.

### Doing A Patch Release

Now that we have our branches, let's say there is a bug in 1.1.2 . You will put the fix into the release-1.1 branch. Increment the version to 1.1.3 in the release-1.1 branch and release 1.1.3 of the product. If users want the latest bug fixes for version 1.1.2, they will have to upgrade to 1.1.3. **Note:** You do NOT create a new branch in this case.

### Doing A Minor Feature Release

Let's say you are working on adding some new features and you are not breaking backward compatibility. Until your features are ready push your commits to your master branch. Once your features are done in the master branch, do the following:

- Create a branch off of master and call it release-1.3 (remember our last version was 1.2).
- Do QA on the branch and fix bugs. Commit the fixes to release-1.3 and cherry-pick them to master if still applicable.
- Once QA is done release version 1.3.0 to customers.

### Doing A Major Feature Release

Let's say you are working on big changes that are backward incompatible (remove old features and changing how existing features work). Push your commits to master until you think everything is done.

- When everything is ready create a new branch off of master called release-2.0.
- Do QA on the branch and fix bugs. Commit the fixes to release-2.0 and cherry-pick them to master if still applicable.
- Once QA is done release version 2.0.0 to customers.

## Release Cycle

The above is all well and good, but how often do you release features? And how long do you support them for? This depends on your customers.

Some ideas for some normalish release schedules are the following:

- Patch releases can be done as frequently as needed to fix bugs for customers. Ex. daily.
- Minor releases can be done every 1 - 4 months
- Major version releases can be done every 1 - 2 years

How long you support a particular major and minor version pair depends on your customer. Are they a slow moving enterprise which needs support for at least 4 years for a particular version? If so you could slow down your Minor and Major releases to reduce the number of versions you have to maintain.

Are they fast moving startups? If so maybe you only support a particular major and minor version pair for 6 months or a year, and require the users to upgrade to a later version for support.

## Conclusion

There are a lot more corner cases and things to consider, but this is a good overview of things to think about. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

- If the five companies require the same features and functions for the product, you can provide the five companies with the same release version from one release branch `release/xx`.
- If the five companies require not all the same features and functions (some may same some may different) for the product, you should use five different branches to provide release version for the five companies separately.

And based on your workflow, it seems all the five companies’ code are same. For this purpose, you can use below workflow:

- `develop` branch: all the developers develop and push their code in this develop. If you do not have this branch, then create it from `master` branch.
- `master` branch: developers create pull requests to merge `develop` branch into `master` branch. And QA team (or someone) can test and approve to merge `develop` branch into `master`. After merging `develop` branch into `master` branch the version on `master` branch is actually ready to release. Then you can record the release version by adding a tag (such as `git tag -a v1.0 -m 'release version 1.0'`), or you can record the release version by creating a release branch `release/xx` from `master` branch.
- Release branches: if you are using `release/xx` to record the release versions from `master` branch, then deliver the r`elease/xx` branches to the five companies for each time release.
- `hotfix` branches: if there has bugs need to fix, you can create a `hotfix` branch from the related `release/xx` branch. After fixing the bug on `hotfix` branch, then merge `hotfix` branch into `master` to test. If it’s ready to release, then create a new `release/xx` branch for the new version from `master` branch.
- Update `develop` branch to the latest version: after every time release new version, merge `master` branch into `develop` branch, so that all developers can continue theirs works on the top of latest version.

Besides, there is [a successful branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), you can also refer it.